# Why does R think my imported vector of characters are numbers?

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv, header-row

This is probably a basic question, but why does R think my vector, which has a bunch of words in it, are numbers when I try to use these vectors as column names?

I imported a data set and it turns out the first row of data are the column headers that I want.  The column headers that came with the data set are wrong ones.  So I want to replace the column names.  I figured this should be easy.

So what I did was I extracted the first row of data into a new object:

```
names <- data[1,]
```

Then I deleted the first row of data:

```
data <- data[-1,]
```

Then I tried to rename the column headers with the "names" object:

```
colnames(data) <- names
```

However, when I do this, instead of changing my column names to the words within the names object, it turns it into a bunch of numbers.  I have no idea where these numbers come from.

Thanks

Comment: *"I imported a data set and it turns out the first row of data are the column headers that I want."*. Show us the first two rows of your data, with `dput()` and `head()`. Also show us the `read.csv()/read.table()` import command you used, did you set `header=TRUE`?.

Comment: I think the problem is that your columns are factors. Try with  `data <- strings("finelname.csv", head = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @Suren: there is no function `base::strings()`, which package do you mean? In any case `read.csv/read.table` is in `utils`, and they already said that solved their issue.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean `strings`.  Not sure how that typo came. I meant, `data <- read.csv("finelname.csv", head = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually show us the data, and the `read.csv()/read.table()` command you used to import.

If R thinks your numeric column is string, it sounds like that's because it wrongly includes the column name, i.e. you omitted `header=TRUE` in your `read.csv()/read.table()` import.

But show us your actual data and commands used.